# Using PHp SDK4 with Javascript SDK to send notifications

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a Facebook canvas application. I did most of the parts using the javascript SDK, and now I am stuck at where I would probably need to use PHP SDK 4 for. I am trying to send notifications to my users. For this purpose, I did some research and could find only limited documentation available. I will summarize through points.

1. I performed all the actions like logging in, retrieving user profile etc etc in JavaScript SDK.
2. Need to use PHP SDK4 for sending out notifications. The following is what I have done so far.

Imported all the required files like require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
and used them like use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;  [ I triple cross checked the paths. They are all correct].

Set a Facebook session like follows.

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx');
```

Obtained a new app access token like follows.

```
$appSession = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
```

Tried to use Graph API to do notification

```
$notification = new FacebookRequest(
$appSession,
'POST',
'/{777911845584420}/notifications',
array (
    'href' => "apps.wehubs.com/ashifshereef/amritham2/againsample/again2/",
    'template' => 'You have been tagged, please set privacy preference',


)
);
$response = $notification->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

I am getting nothing. No Notifications, no anything. I know there is something strange with this code. Something to add, or something not done the right way. I am pretty well versed in javacsript, but not PHP. My Question is, clear. How to make this thing work? Sorry for the junks, Its all I could come up with, with the pretty shitty Documentation available on PHP SDK 4.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use CURL for App Notifications instead:

```
$accessToken = $appId . '|' . $appSecret;
$notificationText = 'The cake is a lie.';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'facebook');

//send notification
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId . '/notifications' .
    '?access_token=' . $accesstoken .
    '&template=' . $notificationText .
    '&href=';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

Source: http://blog.limesoda.com/2014/08/app-notifications-facebook-apps/

As long as the user authorized your App, this should be fine. And keep in mind that you will not see the App Notifications on mobile devices.

One more thing: "apps.wehubs.com/..." is incorrect, it would need to be the absolute URL - or a relative URL for the Canvas (apps.facebook.com/yournamespace/relativeurl). Not sure though if it even works with an external URL, because App Notifications are for Apps on facebook.com only (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications).

Comment: Thanks a Lot. But the thing I am confused about is, The "user authorizing app" was done in Javascript SDK. I am here using the PHP SDK for the first time. Would there be any session issues?

Comment: No, as you need to use an App Access Token for Notifications anyway. The user just needs to be authorized with whatever function you are using, and using the JS SDK for login is the best way. No additional permissioned needed btw.

Comment: Still It is not working. A blank PHP page is shown. Well, if i put the above code in a separate PHP file and configure it with my appid and secret, and call that PHP file from the browser, is it supposed to work isolated from all those JS functions?

Comment: a blank page? what does the browser console say? anyway, there is no echo, you can var_dump $curlResult though.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Curl. Is there any installation I need to do first or,, any libraries I need to Include?  What about these facebook files? 

 require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );

Comment: curl should normally be installed in a default php installation, but some servers don´t allow all urls. for example, i have to tell my provider about every url i want to use with curl and he adds it.

Comment: i really suggest using the code from my answer, no need to deal with the php sdk then - just one file :)

Comment: The Error I am Getting is 

Call to undefined function curl_init() in /srv/www/apps.wehubs.com/ashifshereef/amritham2/againsample/again2/include/index.php on line 63

Comment: oh, that does sound like curl is not installed on your server, i am afraid :(

Comment: Lemme Install it and Will get back to you with the results.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<?php

require ('facebook-sdk/autoload.php');
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

session_start(); 
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>Testing Notifications</div>
<?php 
try {

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(
        "{your_app_id}",
        "{your_app_secret}"
    );

    $appSession = FacebookSession::newAppSession();


        $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $appSession,
            'POST',
            '/'. '{user_id}' .'/notifications',
            array (
                'href' => "index.php",
                'template' => '{your_notification_text}',
            )
        );

        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject(); 

        echo 'Success?: ' . $graphObject->getProperty('success');


}catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo 'FacebookRequestException: ' . $ex->getMessage();

}catch(\Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Exception' . $ex->getMessage();
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```